# Checking stock of every size for a specific product using requests and BS4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So here is my code to check stock of sizes 7.5-9 of a certain product:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get('https://www.jimmyjazz.com/mens/footwear/adidas-solar-hu-nmd/BB9528') 
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
attrs = soup.find_all(class_="box_wrapper")[0].findChildren()

output = str(attrs[0].attrs)
if "piunavailable" in output:
    print("Size 7.5 OOS")
else:
    print("Size 7.5 in stock!")

output = str(attrs[1].attrs)
if "piunavailable" in output:
    print("Size 8 OOS")
else:
    print("Size 8 in stock!")

output = str(attrs[2].attrs)
if "piunavailable" in output:
    print("Size 8.5 OOS")
else:
    print("Size 8.5 in stock!")

output = str(attrs[3].attrs)
if "piunavailable" in output:
    print("Size 9 OOS")
else:
    print("Size 9 in stock!")
```

The actual htmls for the sizes on that website is as follows:

```
<div class="box_wrapper">
     <a href="#" id="itemcode_11468285" class="box">7.5</a>
     <a id="itemcode_11468286" class="box piunavailable">8</a>
     <a id="itemcode_11468287" class="box piunavailable">8.5</a>
     <a id="itemcode_11468288" class="box piunavailable">9</a>
     <a id="itemcode_11468289" class="box piunavailable">9.5</a>
     <a id="itemcode_11468290" class="box piunavailable">10</a>
     <a id="itemcode_11468291" class="box piunavailable">10.5</a>
     <a id="itemcode_11468292" class="box piunavailable">11</a>
     <a id="itemcode_11468293" class="box piunavailable">11.5</a>
     <a id="itemcode_11468294" class="box piunavailable">12</a>
     <a id="itemcode_11468295" class="box piunavailable">13</a>
     <a id="itemcode_11468296" class="box piunavailable">14</a>
</div>
```

So when i run my code, as expected, i get:

```
PS C:\Users\jokzc\Desktop\python\learning requests> py test3.py
Size 7.5 in stock!
Size 8 OOS
Size 8.5 OOS
Size 9 OOS
```

What i would like to do is be able to check every size and return if it is in stock or out of stock without 10 different output blocks in my main code. Is there some forevery function or something i could do that would satisfy this need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it like this.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.jimmyjazz.com/mens/footwear/adidas-solar-hu-nmd/BB9528')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
for anchor_tag in soup.find_all(class_="box_wrapper")[0].findChildren():
    if "piunavailable" in anchor_tag['class']:
        print(f"Size {anchor_tag.text} OOS")
    else:
        print(f"Size {anchor_tag.text}  in stock!")
```

Outputs:

```
Size 7.5  in stock!
Size 8 OOS
Size 8.5 OOS
Size 9 OOS
Size 9.5 OOS
Size 10 OOS
Size 10.5 OOS
Size 11 OOS
Size 11.5 OOS
Size 12 OOS
Size 13 OOS
Size 14 OOS
```

You can also use `for anchor_tag in soup.select('div.box_wrapper a'):` instead of `for anchor_tag in soup.find_all(class_="box_wrapper")[0].findChildren():`